# col-lg doesnt work in ipad landscape (2048px)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">
<div class=" col-md-6 col-lg-2 ">
  foo
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">bar</div>

 foobar
</div>
```

The divs are displayed as 50:50 in ipad landscape (2048px).why?

Comment: No row class surrounding the columns, that's missing. But the reason why is that it's a mega pixel retina device 2048px but the device viewport from the manufacturer is 1024px and col-md-6 is 50% of the min-width:992px until the next min-width of 1200px (large min width).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation of @cab is good and clear. Also read [Responsive Design Mobile and Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720516/responsive-design-mobile-and-desktop/20724367) about the viewport and device width.

If you set `<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">` in your document your columns should work as expected. Also see: [Viewport meta tag for iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892809/viewport-meta-tag-for-ios-devices)